# Prevent newLine while writing javascript in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I´m trying to write a script in my .aspx page but it returs a splited output.
This is my C# code:

```
foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in dt.Rows) {
data +="["+i+","+row["Si"]+"],";
ticks += "[" + i + ",'" + row["id_pieza"].ToString() + "'],";
i++;
}

string options = "var data = ["+data.Substring(0,data.Length-1 )+"]; var options = { lines: { show: true}, points: {show: true},xaxis: {tickDecimals: 0,tickSize: 1,ticks: ["+ticks.Substring(0,ticks.Length-1)+"]}};";


context.Response.Output.Write("<script type ='text/javascript'> "+options+" $.plot('#placeholder', [data], options); </script>");
```

and my output is:

```
var data = [[0,5.84867],[1,5.84867],[2,5.84867],[3,5.84867]]; var options = { lines: { show: true}, points: {show: true},xaxis: {tickDecimals: 0,tickSize: 1,ticks: [[0,'65154S5270SRB0P3
'],[1,'65154S5270SRB0P4
'],[2,'65154S5270SRB0P5'],[3,'65154S5270SRB0P6']]}}; $.plot('#placeholder', [data], options);
```

Firefox throws this error:

> "SyntaxError: unterminated string literal".

How can I prevent the newline when writing JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should sanitize your strings with the the static method [String.Trim()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3(v=vs.110).aspx). For example,
`row["id_pieza"].ToString().Trim()` will remove your white space characters and remove the new lines. Call String.Trim() anywhere you want to remove white space characters.

Also, it is recommended not to do string concatenation inside your aspx markup. I would recommend using a StringBuilder in your code behind and render the formatted string in the markup.

Answer (score 4):

Avoid using string concatenation, instead use StringBuilder class to avoid memory leaks. There you have Append() and AppendLine methods. Use Trim() to remove unnecessary line breaks before appending.